# What does this mean?

Tags: meaning

What does:

> let bygones be bygones

and

> live and let live

mean?

I read it in the book `<<Have Space Suit - Will Travel>>`.

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary? Every decent one should have them.

Comment: You can find these phrases in dictionaries?

Comment: Yes. Check out [Definition #13 of _live_ in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/live), e.g., or look up [_bygones_ in Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bygones). You should at least make an effort first, and share what you find if you still need to ask here. Try asking more along [these lines](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181785/what-is-the-culinary-chops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Let bygones be bygones" is an idiom that's used when two parties have been in conflict with each other, but decide to let go of the conflict.

"Live and let live" is an idiom that means to live with an attitude of acceptance for other peoples' differences.